# ComboBox selection lost when clicked outside of the box

Tags: javafx, combobox

When I click at the outside of a combo box (free space on that window), combo box selection will disappear and print `null`.

This is inside controller class

```
@FXML
public ComboBox routineGridShowComboBox;

public void actionForRoutineGridShowComboBox(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println(routineGridShowComboBox.getValue());
}

public void addOptionToComboBox(){
    routineGridShowComboBox.getItems().removeAll(routineGridShowComboBox.getItems());
    routineGridShowComboBox.getItems().addAll("Hello","World");
}
```

and here is the FXML code:

```xml
<ComboBox fx:id="routineGridShowComboBox" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="56.0" onAction="#actionForRoutineGridShowComboBox" onMouseClicked="#addOptionToComboBox" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="384.0" promptText="Choose your subject ... " />
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. Nobody can possibly know what e. g. `#addOptionToComboBox` does, how your `ComboBox` is filled, what other stuff is happening, etc.

Comment: What you have posted doesn't do what you describe - it clears the items and re-adds them on mouse click. However, I don't really understand why are you doing this. If you want to clear the selection when the combo is opened you can do for example like `routineGridShowComboBox.setOnShowing((e) -> routineGridShowComboBox.setValue(null));`

Answer (score 2):

Every time you open the `ComboBox` popup by clicking on it, you remove all items (which should be done by calling `List.clear` on the items list btw) before readding them. Since the `ComboBox`'s value cannot be something that is not in the `items`, the value is set to `null`. Not selecting a new value by clicking somewhere except the items in the `ComboBox` popup does not change the selected item.

You should definetly not clear and readd all items on every click. Just add the items once. In this case the `initialize` method would be a suitable place to do that.

Remove the `addOptionToComboBox` method from the controller and add

```
public void initialize() {
    routineGridShowComboBox.getItems().setAll("Hello", "World");
}
```

or add the code from the body to an existing `initialize` method.